# Requests failing when made to service URL, but not to version url

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, flask

I'm trying to set up a service on Google App Engine, but am having trouble getting XmlHttp to work consistently with it.

After deploying, the website can be accessed from 2 different urls: `service-dot-project.appspot` and `version-dot-service-dot-project.appspot`, and for some reason there is inconsistencies between the two.

Heres some demo code that verifyably causes me trouble.

```py
# routes.py
from flask import render_template
from . import app

@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():
  return render_template("test.html")

@app.route("/api/test", methods=["GET"])
def api_test():
  return "It Works!"
```

```html
# templates/test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Debug</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="out"></div>
  <button type="button" onclick="run()">
    Test the thing.
  </button>
  <script>
    function run() {
      let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200)
          document.getElementById("out").innerText = xmlHttp.responseText;
      }
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "/api/test", true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```yaml
# service.yaml
runtime: python38
service: name
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
instance_class: F4
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
env_variables:
  ...
```

When I try and press the button on the version url, it works as intended, and "It Works!" gets printed into the div above the button, but on the service url (without the version specified), the page itself loads, but pressing the button causes the request to hang for a few seconds, before printing this to the console:

```
GET https://service-dot-project.appspot.com/api/test [HTTP/2 404 Not Found 7912ms]
```

When testing using a local flask debugging environment, the problem does not occur.

Is there something that Google App Engine does that I should know about that may have caused this issue to happen? Is `/api` a reserved endpoint? The rest of my endpoints works on the service url, its only the api endpoints that break. My only `app.before_request` method fails with a 403, not a 404, so this cannot be the cause.

Comment: Does this just happen with `xmlHttp`, or do you get the same behavior if you make a request directly, e.g. via `curl`? What's the output of `curl -I https://service-dot-project.appspot.com/api/test`?

Comment: Opening the `/api` endpoint in a browser has the same effect. On the version URL, it works as expected, but on the service URL, it doesn't... If I open in curl or postman, I immediately hit a login screen due to Google IAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is being caused by one of the other services running on our project.

Our default service is defining in its dispatch.yaml

```yaml
dispatch:
  - url: "/api*"
    module: otherservice
```

Which is intercepting all the requests made to `myservice-dot-project` and redirecting them to `otherservice-dot-project`

Why this isn't the case for the version url is probably because there is no version of the default service with the same version number.

The fix is to either change the dispatch url of the default service, or change the url of the new service's API endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions

and select your service that is having troubles, is there some other version that is receiving the traffic instead of your desired version?

Also, try going to the logs, find the entry for the 404, expand it and see which version is throwing that error, under `protoPayload` > `versionId`

Comment: All traffic is going towards the version I'm trying to get working. No traffic divide going on.

Comment: I just added an edit, try going to the logs, find the entry for the 404, expand it and see which version is throwing that error, under `protoPayload` > `versionId`

Comment: There is nothing at all in the logs. Successful runs through the version URL are showing up, but whatever is causing the 404s aren't. There are however a lot of tracebacks in there about google cloud debugger. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Maybe share one of those traceback, but i wouldnt think so. If you're not seeing the 404 in your logs at all, then I would think that your app engine service is not even receiving the request in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought too, but I have no way of really figuring out why those requests arent making it. I shouldn't think they are being blocked... I might test with different endpoint names to see if it is that `/api` is a reserved name or something silly like that...

Comment: In order to check in a deeper way your App Engine logs and settings, I would recommend you to open a case with GCP. It is needed more details here understand why this is happening.